# Converting from a C double transferred in two hex strings

Tags: python, string, floating-point, hex, double

my very first day with Python.

I like to filter on a trace file generated by C.
Each double from C is formatted in the file by
two hex strings representing 32 bit of the 64 double.

e.g. 1234567890.3 (C double)
inside file:

```
0xb4933333
0x41d26580
```

How can I parse and combine it to further work with a Python float?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `struct`, using the 'd' modifier for 'double':

```
>>> import struct
>>> num1 = '0xb4933333'
>>> num2 = '0x41d26580'
>>> struct.unpack('!d', (num2[2:]+num1[2:]).decode('hex'))[0]
1234567890.3
```

Be careful what order you append the doubles in, the above assumes a big-endian machine. Also, I stripped `0x` as the `decode` function doesn't expect it.

edit: If you're using Python 3, you need to use `bytes.fromhex` instead of `''.decode('hex')`.

---

Just to give an alternative (the above is a very nice solution):

```
>>> import struct
>>> num1 = '0xb4933333'
>>> num2 = '0x41d26580'
>>> low_word = int(num1, 16)
>>> high_word = int(num2, 16)
>>> representation = struct.pack('>II', high_word, low_word)
>>> result = struct.unpack('>d', representation)
>>> result[0]
1234567890.3
```

Comment: +1 for reminding OP about endianness, definitely something that could trip one up.

Comment: int('0xff', 16) works and looks cleaner, imho. also it would handle some errors more robustly (eg., '0x' being left off in the input).

Comment: What would using `int()` get him here? He's looking for a double representation of an 8 byte string.

Comment: Care to share an example? I agree `int()` is cleaner when you're looking for an integer representation, but he's looking to append two bytestrings and take the double representation of that.

Comment: also: the machine knows its endianess. what he should worry about is the endianess of the file. '!' is for big-endian, no?

Comment: hop, woops, you're totally right. I corrected it to say the code's assuming big-endian.

Comment: @yan: well, it doesn't turn out quite as nice as i thought, but i would still prefer it, especially if written in multiple lines with speaking names: `unpack('!d', pack('!II', int(num2, 16), int(num1, 16)))`

Comment: @hop, yup that's precisely what I tried to do initially, but figured a single decode on two strings was cleaner than an `unpack`/`pack` combo, but both certainly work.

Comment: @yan: i hope you don't mind my edit. and somebody correct me on the low_/high_ confusion. i'm never too clear on that %-/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a the IEEE standard for floating points and how it is created:

http://www.psc.edu/general/software/packages/ieee/ieee.php